# Connect XAMPP and PhpStorm in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, phpstorm

How to connect PhpStorm with XAMPP in Ubuntu?

I'm new to Linux Ubuntu and I installed PhpStorm in software Ubuntu and download and installed XAMPP from friendly Apache site and activated but can't sync them together.

On Windows in `E:\xampp\php\php.exe` was the interpreter but on Linux I can't find anything in this folder and can't create a project in `htdocs` folder

> I wrote this example code:

```
echo "hello world";
```

> but when execute this tell me **bad getway 502**

Comment: Are you trying to run this code from the command line or as a web page?

Comment: @RiggsFolly as a web page

Comment: Did you integrate XAMPP's Apache with PhpStorm? Check https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE